# loop through files and count rows with valid values based on multiple columns

Tags: r, loops

I have a large number of csv files with the same structure.
Each of these files have four columns: A, B, C, D. 
Columns B and C has certain data. column D has the ID of each file.
I have to count the number of rows with a valid, i.e. non "NA", value in columns B and C in each file that is selected by the user.
The target result is a two-column dataframe with the IDs and the counts.
I've started writing a loop but I got stuck...can someone please help me? I am quite new to R.

```
path = "R:\\A\\data\\"
fileList = list.files(path)
file.names = as.numeric(sub("\\.csv$","",fileList))
selected.files = fileList[match(D,file.names)]
n=length(selected.files)
for (i in 1:n) {
  Data<-read.csv(paste(path,selected.files[i], sep=""))
  count1<-length(which(Data[i]$B!="NA"&Data[i]$C!="NA"))
}
result<-c(id, count1)
result
```

Answer (score 0):

loop through files and count rows with valid values based on multiple columns
`Large part of your code is write just couple of lines i have added couple of lines of code, this should work.
{

```
path = "R:\\A\\data\\"    
fileList = list.files(path)  
file.names = as.numeric(sub("\\.csv$","",fileList))   
selected.files = fileList[match(D,file.names)]   
n=length(selected.files)  
for (i in 1:n) {
  Data<-read.csv(paste(path,selected.files[i], sep=""))
  count1<-nrow(Data[complete.cases(Data$B,Data$C),])
  id<-unique(Data$B)
  result<-rbind(c(id, count1))
}

result
```